# Exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

Tags: symfony

1. An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: Illegal string offset 'admin'") in `SonataAdminBundle:Core:add_block.html.twig` at line 5.
2. ContextErrorException: Warning: Illegal string offset 'admin'

I can't understand the problem.

Comment: you should provide more details: what's on 'line 5' of the twig? what parameters do you pass to the twig?

Comment: i don't know exactly

Comment: i just installed userbundle and i got this problem

Comment: foreach ($this->adminGroups as $name => $adminGroup) {
if (isset($adminGroup['items'])) {
foreach ($adminGroup['items'] as $key => $item) {
if (''!= $item['admin']) {
$admin = $this->getInstance($item['admin']);
if ($admin->showIn(Admin::CONTEXT_DASHBOARD)) {
$groups[$name]['items'][$key] = $admin;

Answer (score 0):

It's because something changed in admin-bundle. I've switched back from dev-master to the version 2.3.1, and now it works. You should change the admin-bundle's line in composer.json from:
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
to: 
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3",

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2732